# Legendre transformation of vector valued function

Tags: convex-analysis, duality

Good afternoon. Is there any generalisation of Legendre--Fenchel transformation to the vector-valued functions $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$?

Answer (score 1):

You can start by looking at

*Boţ, Radu Ioan; Grad, Sorin-Mihai; Wanka, Gert*, [**Duality in vector optimization**](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-02886-1), Vector Optimization. Dordrecht: Springer (ISBN 978-3-642-02885-4/hbk; 978-3-642-02886-1/ebook). xv, 400 p. (2009). [ZBL1177.90355](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1177.90355).

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation!